# A hyperbola solves $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. Why is the difference of distances from any point to the two foci constant?

Tags: calculus

I'm interested in this direction, not the other way around.  I know a hyperbola is defined as the set of points for which the distances to two foci have a constant difference and this is the same set of points as the set of solutions for $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.  I can't show how you get from $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ to "for any point on the hyperbola, the distances to the two foci have a constant difference, and that difference is $2a".

Thank you.

Edit, I wrote the equation for an ellipse not a hyperbola, whoops!

Comment: The equations that you’ve got in your question describe ellipses, not hyperbolas. You likely meant $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1$.

Comment: The right equation is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Comment: Can you at least start by identifying the foci of the hyperbola?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I'm asking and what the answer I need is.  Posting for the sake of others who are desperately Googling this.

Known: A hyperbola solving $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ (or equivalently, $y^2=b^2(\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1)$) has focus points $(\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, 0)$.  Sought: The difference of the distances from a point on the hyperbola to each of the focus points.

Let $P = (p, q)$ be a point on the hyperbola.

The distance between $P$ and either focus point (the plus/minus is the only difference) is given by $\sqrt{(p\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2+q^2}$.

$$\sqrt{(p\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2+q^2} = \sqrt{p^2\pm2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}p+a^2+b^2+b^2(\frac{p^2}{a^2}-1)}$$

(expanded the brackets, substituted in expression for $q$ from the above equivalent definition of the hyperbola)

$$\sqrt{(p\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2+q^2} = \sqrt{p^2(1+\frac{b^2}{a^2})\pm2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}p+a^2}$$

(arranged as a quadratic in $p$, cancelled $b^2$ terms)

$$\sqrt{(p\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2+q^2} = \sqrt{(p\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\pm a)^2}$$

(factorised the quadratic; note $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = a\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$)

$$\sqrt{(p\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2+q^2} = p\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\pm a$$

(cancelled the square root)

You now have the distance from $P$ to each focus point.  Take one away from the other to find the difference between them.

$$p\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}+a-(p\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}-a)=2a$$

You can whack some absolute value signs in there to make it work in either direction.  This is a constant and you are done.